# How to use find command to search for a file using his name and permissions in unix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, command

i kept trying using -a and the output always ignores my -perm and just sees the -iname only or other way when i switch them

find .  -perm -0000  -a -iname "R*" #this just filtered using the name only

find . -iname "R*"  -a -perm -0222  #this just filtered using the permissions only

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses to group the tests together.

Example:

```
find . \( -iname "R*" -a -perm -0000 \)
```

Comment: i just tried it but same problem occurs :
mine@amine-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/ex$ find . \( -iname "R*" -a -perm -0000 \)
./R1
./R1/rep1
./R1/rep1/ros
./R1/rep2
amine@amine-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/ex$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amine amine   47 Feb 11 20:39 a
---------- 1 amine amine   15 Feb 11 23:54 pat
drwxrwxr-x 4 amine amine 4096 Feb 11 20:28 R1

Answer (score 0):

nvm guys i ended  up using grep it solved my problem :

```
ls -l | grep "rwxrwxr-x\|R"
```

thank you for trynna help me